# Angular router is not emitting query params when we only change the order

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a big application that uses a backend and we can order by using query params :

> my-resource?field1=asc&field2=desc will gives `order by field1 asc, field2 desc`

but sometimes, i will invert these params :

> my-resource?field2=desc&field1=asc will gives `order by field2 desc, field1 asc`

so in my code, i have a component that emit the new query params using an url tree and `navigateByUrl` :

```
url = 'my-resource';

navigateTo() {
     this.navigateByUrl(this.getUrlTree())
}

getUrlTree() {
    this.router.createUrlTree([this.url], { queryParams: this.orderedQueryParams });
}
```

And i have antother component that listens to the queryParams change :

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
     this._route.queryParams
      .takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
      .do(async params => {
        console.log('params', params);
        this.doRequestToResource(params);
      }).subscribe();
}
```

The problem is that when I navigate from `?field1=asc&field2=desc` to `?field2=desc&field1=asc` I did not receive the event in the queryParams observable, when I go from `field1=asc&field2=desc` to `field1=desc&field2=asc` it works but if we try to invert the order of the parameters, it doesn't emit any observable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since order is important to you maybe another approach is needed for the query params.

One idea would be to use just one query param like this

```
example.is/?q=field1;desc,field2;asc
```

And then in your code you will just have to do some splitting to get the params.

*This is not tested code, just to get the idea across*

```
const splitted = params.split(',') // results = ['field1;desc', 'field2;asc']
const more_split = splitted.map(_ => _.split(';'))
```

Comment: This is a really interesting way to do what I need, I think I will use this solution rather than adding another parameter in the url to keep a url cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Angular is considering this is the same url and will not fire the event.

As a (dirty) workaround you can add a query param to your url with a value which increase (or toggle) each time you call the navigate (of course you have to ignore this param in your backend).

For exemple you can add current timestamp to the query params to force the event to fire:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(path + '&t=' + new Date().getTime());
```

This way, the queryParams change detection occur and the event fire.