# Angular ActivatedRoute subscription with same query parameters

Tags: angular, subscription, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

I have a ActivatedRoute subscription in my angular app which performs some action upon query parameters change. But, when I pass same parameters as previous params the subscription in not triggering. How can the subscription trigger even for same params? I am using dates as parameters. So, there can be same date passed as params multiple times. I tried `queryParamsHandling: "merge" | "preserve" | ""` .

```js
  public constructor(private ac: ActivatedRoute) {}
    
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ac.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log("params", params);
    });
  }
  
  private updateDateQueryParam(): void {
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: {
        to: this.endDate,
        from: this.startDate,
      },
      queryParamsHandling: "",
    });
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular router is not emitting query params when we only change the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407490/angular-router-is-not-emitting-query-params-when-we-only-change-the-order)

Comment: @AliAtaf No, My case is not the order. I am using DateTime. So, if I pass the same DateTime again it should detect the change.

Comment: Yes, but the second answer does have a workaround that solves your case, by adding a query param that always changes value like new Date().getTime() and you can ignore it when you read the query params.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62413663/7024690